How get a wrapped function to return the correct type?
How to get this reduce function to return type Set<1>? (Playground)
const toSet = <const V>(acc=new Set<V>(),v:V) =>{
  acc.add(v);
  return acc;
}
const set = toSet(undefined,1); // Set<1> correct

const reduce = 
  <NextReducer extends (acc:any,value:any)=>any>(nextReducer:NextReducer) =>
    (acc: unknown, value: unknown) =>
      nextReducer(acc, value);

const reduced = reduce(toSet)(undefined,1); // any (should be Set<1>)


TS supports higher order type inference from generic functions but only in specific circumstances. You need reduce to be generic in the argument/return types of nextReducer, not the whole function type. See this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

That does.  Thank you!

TypeScript's support for higher order type inference from generic functions only works in specific limited circumstances, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#30215.  One requirement is that the higher order function needs to be generic in the argument and return types of its input functions separately, and not generic in the entire input function types.
Meaning you cannot write <F extends (acc:any,value:any)=>any>(nextReducer: F)=>⋯ as you've written in your question.  Instead you need to write something like <A, V, R>(nextReducer: (acc: A, value: V) => R)=>⋯. That gives you the following version of reduce:
const reduce =
  <A, V, R>(nextReducer: (acc: A, v: V) => R) =>
    (acc: A, value: V) => nextReducer(acc, value);

The resulting type of reduce is <A, V, R>(f: (a: A, v: V) => R) => (a: A, v: V) => R.
This is safer than your version, since the returned function should not have parameters like (acc: unknown, value: unknown), as nextReducer might not accept unknown arguments. (e.g., nothing stopped someone from calling reduce(toSet)("oops", "darn") and getting a runtime error on "oops".add("darn"))
And, more importantly for your question, this allows the higher order type inference to work:
const reduceToSet = reduce(toSet);
// const reduceToSet: <const V>(acc: Set<V> | undefined, value: V) => Set<V>

You can see that reduce(toSet) preserves the generics from toSet. And thus you get the desired behavior:
const reduced = reduce(toSet)(undefined, 1); 
// const reduce: Set<1>

So that's the answer to the question as asked.
Note that if you're actually planning to try to turn reduce into a real reduction operation which operates on a recursive data structure like an array or tree, you'll probably find that this is more complicated and preservation/propagation of generics might be more difficult or even impossible. But that's outside the scope of the question as asked.
Playground link to code

Thanks for the thoughtful answer. The reduce example was indeed meant to be part of a reduction operation. It was the inner part of a map function for a transduce function. The closest I could get makes it seem possible, but still widens the value to "number".
